# How to fetch selected option in javascript for more than one dropdowns

Tags: javascript, php

I have more than one dropdowns on my page, and I want selected options of each dropdown using their name.

I have tried this method but no success

```
<select name="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>

<select name="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">test1</option>
  <option value="2" >test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

`var e = document.getElementsByName("ddlViewBy");`
`var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;`

https://jsfiddle.net/37zg8u5L/1/

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList`, so you need to access the item(s) on that list via index. Or you use `querySelector` (with an attribute selector for the name) instead.

Comment: As a general rule, you should use unique values for names and ids. That said, you can fetch all `<select>` either with `querySelctorAll('select')` or with `getElementsByTagName('select')`; then you can loop through the returned NodeList and print the value of each `<select>` with `forEach(item => { console.log(item.value) })` or, if you want the text `forEach(item => { console.log(item.children[item.selectedIndex].text) })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to reference elements by name instead of ID, you can use the code below. But keep in mind the elements will need to be the same name (which can be confusing) and you'll have to memorize the indexes of each element you want to reference, so I would strongly recommend assigning IDs instead. Since you are referencing multiple elements, an array of elements will be returned rather than one, which is why your code broke.

```js
var e1 = document.getElementsByName("ddlViewBy")[0];
var e2 = document.getElementsByName("ddlViewBy")[1];
var strUser = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].text;
var strUser2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].text;
console.log(strUser);
console.log(strUser2);
```

```html
<select name="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>

<select name="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">test1</option>
  <option value="2" >test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hey @max, thank you for the solution. Yes I'm aware that I can go with IDs but in this case I had to go with only names that's why I was confused and that's why I asked the question